# why watch cannot work after edit an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array in Vuejs.

```
overtime_rates: [];
```

This array comes from the parent to this page. I sent it through v-model="overtime.overtime_rates" , and take it in the child as:

```
props: {

            value: Array,

        },
        computed: {
            overtime_rates: {
                get() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$emit('input', value);
                }
            },
        },
```

In my method when the array is empty (in create mode) and i try to push the object into it, the watch works fine and can capture all changes for any new push.

```
let rateOT = {     
    startTime: {
       hours: 0,
       minutes: 0,
    },
    endTime: {
       hours: 23,
       minutes: 59,
    },
  } 
this.overtime_rates.push(rateOT);
```

But after i save the array in database and fetch it for edit, when i try to edit each record the  watch cannot catch the changes.

The function which is called in watch is :

```
method: {
   autoTime() {
                for (let i = 1; i < this.overtime_rates.length; i++) {

                    if (this.overtime_rates[i - 1].endTime.minutes >= 0 
                        && this.overtime_rates[i - 1].endTime.minutes < 59) {
                        this.overtime_rates[i].startTime.minutes = 
                              parseInt(this.overtime_rates[i - 1].endTime.minutes) + 1;
                        this.overtime_rates[i].startTime.hours = 
                      parseInt(this.overtime_rates[i - 
  1].endTime.hours);
                    }
                    else if (this.overtime_rates[i - 1].endTime.minutes == 59) {
                        this.overtime_rates[i].startTime.minutes = 0;
                        this.overtime_rates[i].startTime.hours = parseInt(this.overtime_rates[i - 1].endTime.hours) + 1;
                    }
                }

            },
}
```

The watch code is as follow:

```
watch: {
            value: {
                handler: function () {
                    {
                        this.autoTime();
                    }

                },
                deep: true
            },
```

Pleas any one can help me?

Comment: you have to re-watch it after db fetch as it is a new instance and watch was for the previous instance

Comment: @NikosM. thank you so much , may i ask you how can i do rewatch? I edited and  added my watch code in the question.

Comment: hmm i'm afraid I cannot get how you watch the object it is not clear from the code you posted, do you use a polyfill? where exactly does this code reside? what is `this.autoTime()`? these are missing, I can help better if I know that

Comment: Thanks @NikosM. i just afraid that if i put whole code it becomes confusing , i edited again and include the additional code

Comment: Ok I see now, but I think you should post thr code that fetches the array back from db for editing.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with mutation instead of replacement as per the [vuew watch docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)